# Android Google Maps api v2 issues

Tags: google-play-services, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

currently i'm using Google play service r14, i couldn't able to run Google maps API v2 on any device... could anyone say what revision of Google play services be used with google maps API v2, to make simple maps app run correctly...?
It would be a great help.....
Also how to uninstall google play service r14 and install google play service r10 or r12 in sdk?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a sample project in the SDK that does this.

Comment: have tried sample code, it displays FATAL EXCEPTION: main: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity : java.lang.NullPointerException error

Comment: Post the lines where the NullPointerException is raised.

Comment: mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

Comment: mMap is probably null. Look for where is initialized.